# Snapshot testing on Angular 1.x with Jest

Tags: angularjs, testing, snapshot, jestjs

I'd like to use Jest to snapshot-test my angular 1.x directives.
I've already got a working test environment with jest, but I'm not sure how (and if I can) snapshot test my directives/components.

I don't think I can use the renderer object used in this example (looks like a react-specific object) http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/snapshot-testing.html#content and I'm not sure how to use the .toJSON() function in order to serialize my directive/components.

This is the only link I've found on Jest+Angular 1.x usage:
https://medium.com/aya-experience/testing-an-angularjs-app-with-jest-3029a613251 and I can't find any answer about snapshot testing.

Thanks in advance,

Federico

Comment: did you find out anything about this? I would be interested too

Comment: Tobias, sadly no answer and got no time to find out any new answer by myself

Answer (score 3):

It works.

**test.js**

```
const angular = require('angular');
require('angular-mocks');

describe('Renderer', () => {
  let element;
  let scope;

  beforeEach(
    angular.mock.inject(($rootScope, $compile) => {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      element = $compile(
        '<div><label ng-show="label.show">1</label><label ng-hide="label.show">2</label></div>'
      )(scope);
      scope.$digest();
    })
  );

  it('should render the element', () => {
    expect(element).toBeDefined();
    expect(element[0]).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

**Snapshot**

```
exports[`Renderer should render the element 1`] = `
<div
  class="ng-scope"
>
  <label
    class="ng-hide"
    ng-show="label.show"
  >
    1
  </label>
  <label
    ng-hide="label.show"
  >
    2
  </label>
</div>
`;
```

Comment: In your example you are using a hardcoded string for the template. How do you import and use an HTML template? How do you inject variables into the template?

Comment: Template is depending on your setup. You could require the html in `$compile` call or make use of the `$ngTemplateCache`. I'm already using variables in my template `label` is a variable on the `$scope`. The scope is required in the second braces of the `$compile` call